# Altium designer routing problem

Tags: altium

this is more of a 'I have no ideas how to route this part' than 'I don't how to technically route this part'. Or maybe both. Basically I have no ideas how to route and what to do here.

[image: Routing problem]

R35 cant access those pins which is a big problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Vias? Does it have to be single layer? Can you route through the pads on the top layer?

Comment: Multi layer. Vias are way larger than the actual pads, so they would be bigger than the pads. The third question I dont understand, sorry.

Comment: What is the pitch of the IC? What is the diameter of the ball pads?

Comment: @Ben, Drew's third question is asking can't you just run a trace between two balls to connect to the inner pads. You haven't shared the pad diameters or spacing, so we don't know whether this is possible or not.

Comment: Is via-in-pad an option?  As the designer, you determine the size of vias.  What are your trace/space restraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way this is typically done is with micro vias (via less than 6 mil in diameter), this will also add manufacturing cost. Compare the manufacturing cost to the cost of the package (if there are different options go with a different package).

You'll need to add another via size in the [via template](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/PCB_Prop-Via((Via+Properties))_AD) and change the DRC rules if you use them.

[image]

Source: https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/649693